# Getting normalized values from two foreign key fields, SQL, double join?

Tags: sql

An example is the easiest way to explain what I'm looking to do:

GIVEN:

```
~move~
id | from | to
--------------
 1 |  1   | 2
 2 |  1   | 2
 3 |  2   | 3
 4 |  3   | 1

 ~locations~ 
 id | name
 ---------
  1 | home
  2 | work
  3 | out
```

How can I get:

```
id | from | to
----------------
 1 | home | work
 2 | home | work
 3 | work | out
 4 | out  | home
```

That is, the human-readable name for *both* the `from` and `to` columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select
  Move.ID,
  [From] = FromLocation.Name,
  [To] = ToLocation.Name
From
  Move
  Inner Join Location As FromLocation On Move.[From] = FromLocation.ID
  Inner Join Location As ToLocation On Move.[To] = ToLocation.ID
```